# Is limit required for expectation in probability generating function (PGF)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

The [probability generating function(PGF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) of a discrete random variable is a power series representation
$$PGF=G(z)$$

> that converges absolutely at least for complex numbers z with $|z|\leq1$.

But when calculating the expectation, the same page defines
$$E[X]=G'(1-)$$

If the convergence is gauranteed for complex numbers with magnitude 1 or less, why do we need to take the left hand limit?

Comment: $G(x)$ need not be defined for $x \in (1,\infty)$. But there are examples where it is defined for all $x$. So you don't always think of $G$ as  function defined on $[0,1]$. Also, $EX$ and $G'(1-)$ don't always exist. They are equal when they exist.

Comment: If it need not be defined for $x=1$, then why is absolute convergence gauranteed for $|z|\leq1$, which also includes $z=1$.

Comment: It is defined for $z=1$ but that doesn't mean $G'(1-)$ is bad notation. I don't even see what your objection is.

Comment: If the function is defined for $z=1$ wouldn't the limit be calculated by simple substitution? And then the limit is trivial. So what is the benefit of writing it as a limit?

Comment: You can differentiate a power series term by term inside the interval of convergence but not on the boundary.

Comment: This is G' (derivative), not G. The fact that G converges absolutely at 1 does not mean G' does.

Comment: Understood. This is exactly what I wanted to understand. If you write this an answer, I can accept.